# VAADIN - Button | implement in HTML Layout-Script

Tags: html, button, components, vaadin, getelementbyid

is there any oportnunity to use a Vaadin Button in a HTML script?

Id like to use the following button

```
Button button_login = ew Button();
button_login.setID("buttonlogin");
```

and this button should be implement in the following script

```
<div data-location="buttonlogin"></div>
```

(Only an idea)

Have so. an idea to bind the button in the html script?

Thank!

Comment: If you want to generate HTML from Vaadin, a simple start to do so is using a `Label` with `Content.HTML` (beware for XSS). If you plan on something else, please add some substance to the question.  What is a "html script" and a "html layout script"?

Answer (score 3):

I am quite unsure what you mean by *html script*. If it is something you can achieve using JavaScript then here is my try.

Generally to execute JavaScript on button click

```
Button js = new Button("Do JavaScript");
js.addClickListener( click -> { 
   com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("alert(´Hello´)");
 });
```

When in need to use external `.js` files, for example `hello.js`, contents below

```
function hello() {
   alert("Hello JavaScriptWorld!");
}
```

Assuming `hello.js` is directly under `/VAADIN/` directory, add following annotation to your `UI` or relevant component class

```
@JavaScript({"vaadin://hello.js"}) // all paths must be relative to /VAADIN
```

Then in `ClickListener` you can refer to `function hello()` like

```
com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("hello()");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Java
@com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript("vaadin://themes/paastheme/layouts/ui/donut/donut.js")
public class BrowsePeopleUI extends UI {}`

I put JS file to:

`src/main/resources/VAADIN/themes/paastheme/layouts/ui/donut/donut.js`

My donut.js is:

`Javascript
var util = util || {};
util.donut = () => {console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[data-svg]"))};`