# Vaadin 8: how to include a JavaScript File to returned web page and execute it

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

For instance: 
    I have a html file and a JavaScript file. If two file open directly with browser. It can be work.
    If put these file to Vaadin Frame and use @JavaScript annotation running, it only shows a static html.
Only need communication between JavaScript and html page, no need with server.
here my code

Html(example.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Js Test Uses</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mylibrary.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.foo = new mylibrary.MyComponent(document.getElementById("foo"));
        window.foo.click = function () {
               alert("Value is " + this.getValue());
           }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

mylibrary.js

```
var mylibrary = mylibrary || {};

mylibrary.MyComponent = function (element) {
    element.innerHTML = "<div class='caption'>Hello, kitty!</div>" 
        + "<div class='textinput'>Enter a value: " 
        + "<input type='text' name='value'/>"
        + "<input type='button' value='Click'/>"
        + "</div>";

    element.style.border="thin solid red";
    element.style.display="inline-block";

    this.getValue = function() {
        return element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    };

    this.setValue = function (value) {
        element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = value;
    };

    this.click = function () {
        alert("Error: Must implement click() method");
    };

    var button = element.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
    var self = this;
    button.onclick = function () {
        self.click();
    };
};
```

Vaadin (MyUI.java):

```
@Theme("mytheme")
@JavaScript("mylibrary.js")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6891373465168098637L;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        CustomLayout layout = null;
        try {
            layout = new CustomLayout(MyUI.class.getResourceAsStream("examples.html"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -9170703857949837824L;
    }
}
```

[this is my project package explorer image, is a initial project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJhJ3.png)

[this is my project source(zip)](http://us.broderick.cn/d/examples.zip)

Comment: Can you update your question with information where do you have these files in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible the way you want. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30309325/6413377).

Annotation `@JavaScript` has a bit different purpose. It enables you to call script from `Vaadin` server side code.

For using `@JavaScript` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47444500/6413377). Pay attention especially to the path the script is included.

So basically `@JavaScript` allows you to do things like

```
com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("hello()");
```

where `hello()` is a function declared in a `javascript` you include with `@JavaScript`